# jQuery Mobile Header and footer take a lot of space when in landscape mode on iphone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation, progressive-enhancement

Is there a way to keep the same size that a header has in portrait mode when you change the orientation to landscape mode in Jquery Mobile?. when you are working with a webapp you have your header and your footer which have approximately a height of 45 px but when you change the orientation to landscape the header and footer take much space not allowing the user to view the page content properly. If anyone knows about a work around for this. Please let me know. Thank you.

Here's a screenshot in portrait mode, which is fine:

[image]

and Here is the one in landscape mode which takes up a lot of space on the screen:

[image]

How can we keep the same height of the header when phone changes orientation?

Comment: If you could post few Screenshots from your iPhone it'll be easy for us to understand your question more clearly.

Comment: Hi Rohit, I´m talking about a regular header on JQM, just as follows: <div data-role="header" data-id="1" class="ui-bar-t" data-position="fixed">  
<h1>Books</h1>   
</div>

Comment: Hi chmzzy, I will post a few screenshots as you suggest

Comment: Don't show the footer at all in landscape? Show it and make it fade out after a second? Show it at 50% opacity? Ask Apple to make a wider phone? Don't make them fixed at all so you can scroll them on/off the screen? Lock the orientation of the page to it doesn't flip to landscape? Have a different footer with 1/2 height icons/font for landscape mode?

Comment: How can you lock the orientation of the page in a webapp using jquery mobile? That would be an alternative, to force it not to change when the mobile device is in landscape....